# How secure are XPS documents?

Tags: security, xps, xpsdocument

How secure are XPS documents? After looking from the inside of an [XPS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open_XML_Paper_Specification) document, found the Unicode-string property. Could someone inject e.x. a script into the Unicode string property?

How does the XPS viewer treat the Unicode string property? As a collection of glyphs or what?

**UPDATE:** I added the following string as UnicodeText

```
!@#$%^&*()_+
```

and the XPS viewer refused to open the file. This is how this question came into my mind

Answer (score 16, accepted):

XPS documents, as opposed to *(coughs)* [some other format](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PDF) cannot contain scripts or active content. They are *only* used as a high-fidelity pre-print format. That being said, it's not entirely impossible for XPS parsers to contain security vulnerabilities. And they can be exploited. So far I haven't heard of any such exploits, though.

But back to your point. If someone wants to put a script into a string in an XPS document he can surely do so. He just shouldn't expect it to be executed. If some software actually *does* that, then it's probably a security problem with the software and not with the file format.

Just because you can put malware into a text file (remember iloveyou.vbs?) that doesn't mean that text files themselves have a security vulnerability :-)

**ETA:** The UnicodeString attribute in question aids searching inside the XPS file:

> The UnicodeString attribute holds the array of Unicode scalar values that are represented by the current  element. Specifying a Unicode string is RECOMMENDED, as it supports searching, selection, and accessibility.

And while the string itself is expected to be in a certain format (also detailed in the standard on page 115), the reason why the viewer didn't want to accept your input is that it's not even well-formed XML since the ampersand (`&`) appears unescaped. I assume that it would work if you encode the ampersand as `&amp;` as required by XML. The spec also states that

> The standard XML escaping mechanisms are used to specify XML-reserved characters.

But even with that in place, the relationship between the UnicodeString attribute and other parts of the document are quite intricate. They wrote over half a page on that and which combinations are valid and which are not. So I'd suggest you read up on that first, before trying to play around further :-)

Comment: Where is the six stars option? +10 from me

Answer (score 1):

p.95 of the XPS 1.0 spec: "The standard XML escaping mechanisms are used to specify XML-reserved characters."

The '&' might be causing troubles.